# How do I use a checkbox to decorate texts?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

I'm trying to build a To-Do App with Javascript, right now I'm trying to figure out, how to strike through a todo item with a checkbox and undo that. I've already tried to achieve the same with a button and I got the text to be striken through when I clicked the button, but I couldn't figure out how to undo it.

```js
function newToDo() {
    if (document.getElementById("input_todo").value == "") {
        confirm("Bitte füllen sie es aus.")
    } else {
        var newLi = document.createElement("LI");
        newLi.id = "itemLi";
        newLi.innerHTML = document.getElementById("input_todo").value;
        var allTodos = document.getElementById("allTodos");
        var checkBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
        checkBox.id = "checkBox";
        checkBox.type = "checkbox";
        var buttonDel = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        buttonDel.id = "buttonDel";
        buttonDel.setAttribute('onclick', "delToDo()");


        allTodos.appendChild(newLi);
        newLi.appendChild(checkBox);
        newLi.appendChild(buttonDel);
        document.getElementById("input_todo").value = "";

        if (checkBox.checked == "true") {
            document.getElementById("itemLi").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("itemLi").style.textDecoration = "none";
        }
    }    
}
function delToDo() {
    allTodos.removeChild(itemLi);
}
```

```css
#input_todo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#but_todo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
#itemDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#buttonJa {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
#buttonDel {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todo.css" media="screen">
        <title>To-Do</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To-Do Liste</h1>
        <input id="input_todo" type="text">
        <button id="but_todo" onclick="newToDo()">Create To-Do</button>
        <ul id="allTodos">

        </ul>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to style something like a checkbox use a `<label>` element. When connected to the input with the `for` attribute, it can be clicked to check or uncheck an input. Same goes for all other input elements and label combinations.

And when it comes to styling, simply resort to CSS. the `:checked` pseudo-selector of an input can check if an input is checked and change the style accordingly.

If you are going to create elements and append them to the document, then don't use the `id` attribute, but use classes instead. Ids have to be unique or else they are useless.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
  transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}

label:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transform: translate3d(0, -2px, 0);
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: -5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left center;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="task-1" type="checkbox" name="task" value="done">
      <label for="task-1">Task that I have to do</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="task-2" type="checkbox" name="task" value="done">
      <label for="task-2">Another task that I have to do</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```